# Dask distributed.utils_test.client doesn't inherit parent process environment variables?

Tags: pytest, dask, dask-distributed

I am using pytest to test my dask workflows. I have a specific workflow, `ingest_l0_files` that uses a `Client` to map out tasks to workers. During testing, I need to artificially set a directory path that is set in an environment variable called `CURRENT_RUN_LOG_PATH`. Importantly, this setup works flawlessly during integration testing and real runs; I set the environment variable in my driver script and all my workers have access to it (because they are spawned from thy master process presumably). However, in my pytest, the (artificially set) environment variable is unavailable to the workers. Why? Perhaps I can tell my `utils_test.client` to re-initialize its environment and then pass it to its workers?

```
from distributed.utils_test import client
def test_ingest_l0_files(client, clean_database_fixture, tmpdir):
    """Test the workflow function `ingest_l0_files`"""
    os.putenv('CURRENT_RUN_LOG_PATH', f'{tmpdir}')
    get_config('CURRENT_RUN_LOG_PATH')
    client = client()
    unique_obs = workflow.ingest_l0_files([L0_ALL_FILE, L0_LPT_FILE], client)
    assert len(unique_obs) == 20
    os.unsetenv('CURRENT_RUN_LOG_PATH')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the `client` pytest fixture is not particularly extensible.

If you are comfortable with async programming then I recommend the `@gen_cluster` decorator, which provides many more options:

```
@gen_cluster(
    client=True,
    Worker=Nanny,
    worker_options={"env": {"FOO": "BAR"}},
)
async def test_foo(client, scheduler, worker_a, worker_b):
    await ...
```

But this would require that your code is async-friendly, which may or may not be the case.  If you call non-async methods then this test will block unhelpfully.

https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/develop.html#writing-tests

Comment: We're really just using Dask as a process pool (I didn't make architecture decisions) so none of our code is async friendly. Every worker task blocks until it returns.